# In Microsoft Access, how do I add time fields together and then output the total as 2 hours and 45 minutes as opposed to 2.75 hours.?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to work out the total amount of time spent working, with multiple (up to 3) start and finish times in a day: Start Time 1, Finish Time 1, Start Time 2, Finish Time 2, Start Time 3, Finish Time 3.

The first problem I'm having is with calculating the total time, Start Time 1 and Finish Time 1 will always have an entry, but the other fields will not always be populated, so when I add these together unless every field has an entry my addition calculation will not work. How do I add these together with the empty cells being added as a 0?

Secondly, how do I display the total time as x hours and y minutes, instead of hours with a decimal place? (Example: 2 hours and 45 minutes, instead of 2.75 hours).

Thanks in advance.

[Time total query with empty cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L64b.png)

Comment: I think it depends on what you're trying to do in code vs. what you're trying to do in queries, but I'd suggest that if you're working in code (and if VB.NET is actually what you mean and not VBA), it should be straightforward to skip a pair that isn't specified.  Your start and finish will be `System.DateTime` (I believe the VB `Date` is an alias for this), so if you subtract, you get a `TimeSpan`, which will already be broken down as you want (and can be added to another `TimeSpan` to get a total duration).

Comment: In your example it looks like your tables might not be normalized.  if that is the case it would be best replace all those times with clockDate(an actual datetime), clocktype (enumeration like 1 = clock in), employeeid (from linked employeeTable).  Interact with the data and do the formatting in forms, queries, and reports.  This avoids many gotcha's later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access, it could be (the *ControlSource* of the textbox):

```vb
= CDate(Nz(CVDate([Finish Time]), #00:00#) - Nz(CVDate([Start Time]), #00:00#) + _
    Nz(CVDate([Finish Time 2]), #00:00#) - Nz(CVDate([Start Time 2]), #00:00#) +  _
    Nz(CVDate([Finish Time 3]), #00:00#) - Nz(CVDate([Start Time 3]), #00:00#))
```

Apply the Format `h:nn` to the textbox where you display the total time.